# Return data using signalR with ApiController and reactjs fetch?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a function in my WebApi controller:

```
[HttpPost,Route("GetCurrenciesData")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCurrenciesData(InputCurrenciesData cls)  
{
    try
    {
        var data = GetBL.myMethod(cls.currenciesList);
        return Ok(data);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteError(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

The `data` which returns is a List of classes

In my client I have `httpRequest` (reactJs fetch).

`myMethod` do what it needs to do - Iterate a loop on the `currenciesList`,
 the data which "born" in every iterate adding to a List.
When I finish , the List return back to the controller and then to client.

What I want to do is to change the way it works, and on every iteration (inside the loop in `GetBL.myMethod()`) send the data thru SignalR to client and like that I will not have to wait to all the iterations to finish (which takes a lot of time..).

First of all, is it possible?
I need to change my `httpRequest` to something else? Because I read that I need to connect to the SignalR.
My `BL` can works like SignalR for only one function?
How can I achieve my needs? Where I need to start? I kinda lost

Thanks guys

Comment: I'm not familiar with SignalR currently, but have you considered the method to return an IEnumerable instead of IHttpActionResult and using yield return ?

Comment: Actually I don't. It will works? It will gives the same result (The client will receive and data one by one)? @T.Aoukar

Comment: I'm not sure since I haven't used it before, but it's worth trying.

Comment: I tried this idea but I didn't work .. the client receive the data just after them all yield, just the client get an array (like before) @T.Aoukar